# Use ErrorResponse from java client library generated with swagger-codegen

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp, swagger-codegen

I have a Java client sdk created with Swagger codegen for the backend API. I need to use this in android app.

The backend developer has defined ErrorResponse models and I can see those model classes in the generated code. But I see no way to read the error responses deserialised to the corresponding type.

Below is my code

```
new DefaultApi().loginAsync(loginRequest, new ApiCallback<LoginSuccessResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(ApiException e, int statusCode, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) {
            String responseBody = e.getResponseBody();
            //I can access the response body as string.
            //Is it possible to access the response body as an object corresponding the model
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginSuccessResponse result, int statusCode, Map<String, List<String>> responseHeaders) {
            LoginSuccessResponse iCanGetTheSuccessResultHere = result;
        }

        @Override
        public void onUploadProgress(long bytesWritten, long contentLength, boolean done) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDownloadProgress(long bytesRead, long contentLength, boolean done) {

        }
    })
```

In case of failure I am able to access the response body as string.
Is it possible to access the response body as an object corresponding the model.

In the generated code I can see classes like 'LoginFailedResponse' and 'ErrorResponse' but no idea how I can read the response as one of those types.